# Where can i find old archived patient records from 19th century psychiatric hospitals?

Tags: psychology

I do not have university access and do not want to spend money on protected documents. I am looking for free access. (Possibly I would spend money for original documents which should then be sent to me. ;) )

Comment: Perhaps a better place to ask this would be here - https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for *patient records from 19th century psychiatric hospitals* (no quotes) turns up relevant results, though not for free access.

For example, here's a service from [The National Archives](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/mental-health/) (UK) that looks like exactly what you're talking about. And another one from [New Zealand](https://archives.govt.nz/mental-health). I'm sure there are more.